# Omitting props in HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Have an unusual question about omitting props in HoC

I have react component:

```js
interface IMyComponentProps {
  prop1: string,
  prop2: Function,
  items1: string[],
  items2: string[],
}
```

and i have HOC which takes this component and pass items1 and items2 to it

```js
interface IWithItems {
  items1: string[],
  items2: string[],
}

type WithoutItems<T extends IWithItems> = Omit<T, 'items1'|'items2'>;


function HoC<T extends IWithItems>(
  WrappedComponent:
    React.ComponentClass<T>
    | React.FunctionComponent<T>,
): React.ComponentClass<WithoutItems<T>> {
  class WithItemsWrapper extends React.Component<WithoutItems<T>, IWithItems> {

    state = {
      items1: [],
      items2: [],
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
      const items1 = await this.getItems1();
      const items2 = await this.getItems2();

      this.setState({
        items1,
        items2,
      });
    }

    getItems1 = () => (
      // from backend
    );

    getItems2 = () => (
      // from backend
    );

    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          {...this.props}
          items1={this.state.items1}
          items2={this.state.items2}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  return hoistNonReactStatics(WithItemsWrapper, WrappedComponent);
}
```

Wrapped component has own props and these props contains items1, items2.
HoC pulling items from backend and pass it to wrapped component

at my `index.ts` file i exporting it as

```js
export default HoC(MyComponent);
```

the idea is that after this export and import this in other file `MyComponent` should require prop1 and prop2, but not items1 and items2, cuz they had already passed in HoC.

But now it says

```
Error:(59, 12) TS2322: Type 'Readonly<Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "items1" | "items2">>> & { items1: never[]; items2: never[]; children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & T & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type 'Readonly<Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "items1" | "items2">>> & { items1: never[]; items2: never[]; children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

Is it possible and if it is - what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the solution

First of all simplify WithoutItems and change HOC definition

```js
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type Diff<T, K> = Omit<T, keyof K>;

type WithoutItems<T> = Diff<T, IWithItems>;

function HoC<P>(
  WrappedComponent:
    React.ComponentClass<P>
    | React.FunctionComponent<P>,
): React.ComponentClass<WithoutItems<P>> {
  class WithItemsWrapper extends React.Component<WithoutItems<P>, IWithItems> {
```

and next thing is to make props map explicitly type P

```js
// HoC render method
  render() {
    return (
      <WrappedComponent
        {...this.props as P}
        items1={this.state.items1}
        items2={this.state.items2}
      />
    );
  }
```

all other things stay as they were.

---

solution founded [here](https://dev.to/busypeoples/notes-on-typescript-pick-exclude-and-higher-order-components-40cp)

Answer (score 0):

You did opposite way. `HoC` accepts component with `items1` and `items2` and returns HOC without `items1` and `items2`. So for component

```
let ResultingComponent = HoC(MyComponent);
```

you should provide only `prop1` and `prop2`. `items1` and `items2` will be filled from HoC.

If you want pass component without `items1` and `items2` but have resulting component contain `items1` and `items2` you should do like this

```
function HoC<T>(
    WrappedComponent:
        React.ComponentClass<T>
        | React.FunctionComponent<T>,
): React.ComponentClass<T & IWithItems> {
    class WithItemsWrapper extends React.Component<T & IWithItems, IWithItems> {

        render() {
            return (
                <>
                // Do some rendering based on this.props.items1 and this.props.items2
                    <div>{this.props.items1.map(e => (<div>{e}</div>))}</div>
                    <WrappedComponent
                        {...this.props}
                    />
                </>
            );
        }
    }

    return hoistNonReactStatics(WithItemsWrapper, WrappedComponent);
}
```

But please note that in this case `item1` and `item2` should be provided to resulting component from HoC. Inside HoC you shouldn't receive these props from backend, But you should render something based on these props and don't pass them to `WrappedComponent`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I think it's not quite what i'm looking for.

Component should expect items1 and items2 based on its interface.. But i'm trying to separate fetching data from backend to HOC, to simplify Component testing.

the idea is about I can import component and pass these two props from whatever place, but if I don't want to do this I can import component wrapped by this HOC and get it to work by itself.

the goal - props items1 and items2 should exist on component, but when it wrapped by HOC they shouldn't, cuz they passed from HOC.

Maybe I thinking in a bad way?